# Make taxonomy query dynamic

Tags: taxonomy

I'm using the same page template for multiple pages. `-> page-base.php`

On each page using this template, I want to display categories, created with a `CPT`.

My question is, how can I make my array dynamic, to change the 'taxonomy' automatically?

This is my current code

```
<?php  

    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'catmaison',
            'hide_empty' => false,
    ));



if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
            "posts_per_page" => 1,
            "orderby" => 'date', 
            "order" => 'DESC',
            "tax_query" => array(
                array (
                'taxonomy' => 'catmaison',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $term->term_id,
                ),
            ),
            ) );

?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
$taxonomy = get_field('taxonomy');

                $terms = get_terms(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                ));



                if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
                // Run a loop and print them all
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                        $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                        "posts_per_page" => 1,
                        "orderby" => 'date', // this is the default
                        "order" => 'DESC', // this is the default
                        "tax_query" => array(
                            array (
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, // use the $tax you define at the top of your script
                            'field' => 'term_id',
                            'terms' => $term->term_id, // use the current term in your foreach loop
                            ),
                        ),
                        ) ); ?>





                                    <!--LOOP CONTENT -->
                                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-20 cpt-categories">

                                            <div class="cat-images">
                                            <!-- Image -->
                                            <?php 

                                            $image = get_field('image_category', $term);

                                            if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="img-fluid pb-20" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <!-- Image -->
                                        </div>


                                        <?php $pageone = get_the_permalink($the_query->posts[0]); ?>

                                        <h4><a href="<?php echo $pageone; ?>"><?= $term->name ?></a></h4>
                                            <?php echo $cat; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--LOOP CONTENT -->

            <?php
            } // End foreach
            } // End if 

            //endif; ?>
```

So i've updated my code like you tell me to do.

I'm using ACF Pro the my website.
But i don't understand your proposal.

This is that i think you tell me to di, that's right ?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Did it work? Please write an answer if you used another solution.

Comment: Sorry for late. I've tried your answer but it didn't work.. so i dont know how to do

Comment: Hi, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. please check my uptade above

Comment: Ohh, i've found the solution. I've just re-read and re-read your solution to understand. Thanks a lot for your answer, you saved my life !

Comment: I'm so glad you found a solution, but please mark my answer as complete ("accept" it) so that this question has an accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

For example, you could name it `taxonomy`, and then in your template, use `get_post_meta()` to retrieve the taxonomy:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID(); // the ID of the current post
$taxonomy = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'taxonomy', true );
```

And change the `'taxonomy' => 'catmaison'` in your code to:

```
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy
```

Example:

```
$terms = get_terms(
  array(
    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => false,
  ),
);
```

---

### UPDATE

I normally don't suggest any plugins in my answer, but in your case, it might be easier for you to just use a plugin like [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

So go ahead, install and activate it, and follow the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) on creating a custom field. But as an example, let's use the same name as I've suggested before: `taxonomy`. It should be a simple [Text](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/text/) field:

*(Update: For other readers, the text field looks like below.)*

[image]

Now in your page template, you can use this code to retrieve the taxonomy (slug) associated with the specific page:

```
$taxonomy = get_field( 'taxonomy' );
```

And then as I've mentioned before, change the `'taxonomy' => 'catmaison'` in your code to:

```
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy
```